# deriving shrinkage factors for beta binomial distributions

Tags: multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, hyperparameter, regularization, beta-binomial-distribution

I am confused by the derivation of [shrinkage factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Shrinkage_factors) currently online on sites like Wikipedia and ProbWiki.

To be on point, I am confused how we get quickly from $\theta_i \sim Beta(\mu,M)$ to $E(\theta)=\mu$. Isn't the expected value of the distribution $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ just $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$? I am pretty sure it is, but then does the derivation here changed notation along the way? Or it's not correct at all? What is the correct result (and derivation), and what is a good source on that, if these are not?

Otherwise the exercise seemed reasonable, but doesn't behave well in simulation.

For context, my application is based on estimating group-level means (of a Bernoulli variable), but shrinking towards the population mean, the more the smaller the group. This is an Empirical Bayes exercise, or fitting a hierarchical or multilevel model but caring only about the point estimate, not going fully Bayesian.

This somewhat to similar to what is discussed in [this blogpost](http://andrewgelman.com/2012/12/30/fixed-effects-followed-by-bayes-shrinkage/), though not for normally distributed coefficients (as for teacher value added), but recovering the Bernoulli failure rate for each unit.

Comment: I don't know that I'd call Wikipedia *authoritative* on matters relating to statistics (there's too many things that are wrong, overly narrow, confusing or misleading, though most of what's there is broadly okay). It's a very useful resource but it doesn't pay to rely on it too heavily (it's useful for checking details of things you already mostly know, because then it's easy to spot errors).

Comment: Currently the only question your post contains is "Isn't the expected value of the distribution Beta(α,β) just α/(α+β)?" (to which the answer - yes -  is readily obtained from the wikipedia page for the beta). Other than that your post consists entirely of statements, making it hard to tell what you seek, precisely. Are you able to reword so that you're asking some specific questions?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. I think the implied question: Is the derivation still correct, and if so, why? Or am I missing a change in notation in the derivation that should be pointed out? Or what is a better source on the "same" (but correct) derivation and result?